# ImportError with pyfmi

Tags: python, fmi, jmodelica

I am tying to use pyfmi on our universities Linux HPC cluster. Building the FMILibrary and also installing pyfmi does not throw any error. However I get the below error message when trying to import pyfmi in python:

File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyfmi/**init**.py", line 24, in 
    from .fmi import FMUModel, load_fmu, FMUModelME1, FMUModelME2
ImportError: /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyfmi/fmi.so: undefined symbol: __intel_sse2_strcpy

Does anyone have an idea what the reason might be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you could be interested in FMPy as an alternative to pyFMI: As it is (except for the Sundials solver) written in pure python, you could avoid perhaps such library-related errors. https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I solved the above problem.

pyfmi was built from source using the intel compiler instead of gcc. So with:

module switch intel gcc

this error didnt occur anymore.